# Thread safe holder

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

**EDIT: I moved this question to codereview** https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105742/thread-safe-holder

I have implemented a thread safe holder to safely pass data between threads.

User can set value many times, but only the first `SetIfEmpty` call stores the value, then user may read the value many times.

```
template <typename T>
class ThreadSafeHolder {
public:
    ThreadSafeHolder() : is_value_set_(false) {
    }

    void SetIfEmpty(const T& value) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        // memory_order_relaxed is enough because storing to
        // `is_value_set_` happens only in `SetIfEmpty` methods
        // which are protected by mutex.
        if (!is_value_set_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            new(GetPtr()) T(value);
            is_value_set_.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }

    void SetIfEmpty(T&& value) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (!is_value_set_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            new(GetPtr()) T(std::move(value));
            is_value_set_.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }

    //! This method might be safely call only if previous `IsEmpty()`
    //! call returned `false`.
    const T& Get() const {
        assert(!IsEmpty());
        return *GetPtr();
    }

    bool IsEmpty() const {
        // memory_order_acquire loading to become synchronize with
        // memory_order_release storing in `SetIfEmpty` methods.
        return !is_value_set_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }

    ~ThreadSafeHolder() {
        if (!IsEmpty()) {
            GetPtr()->~T();
        }
    }

private:
    T* GetPtr() {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(value_place_holder_);
    }

    const T* GetPtr() const {
        return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(value_place_holder_);
    }

    // Reserved place for user data.
    char value_place_holder_[sizeof(T)];
    // Mutex for protecting writing access to placeholder.
    std::mutex mutex_;
    // Boolean indicator whether value was set or not.
    std::atomic<bool> is_value_set_;
};
```

**Questions**

- Is the code correct in general?
- Is access to `is_value_set_` member properly synchronized?
- Might be access to `is_value_set_` member even more relaxed?

**Application**

I wanted to develop such holder to pass active exceptions from worker threads to main thread.

Main thread:

```
ThreadSafeHolder<std::exception_ptr> exceptionPtrHolder;
// Run many workers.
// Join workers.
if (!exceptionPtrHolder.IsEmpty()) {
    std::rethrow_exception(exceptionPtrHolder.Get());
}
```

Worker thread:

```
try {
    while (exceptionPtrHolder.IsEmpty()) {
        // Do hard work...
    }
} catch (...) {
    exceptionPtrHolder.SetIfEmpty(std::current_exception());
}
```

**Note about `std::promise`**

`std::promise` is not suitable here (despite the fact that `std::promise::set_value` is thread safe) because

> An exception is thrown if there is no shared state or the shared state already stores a value or exception.

Comment: You may want to use [`std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) instead of your char array

Comment: Also, this question might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, I posted it here accidentally, thank you for pointing me.
This question on codereview [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105742/thread-safe-holder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105742/thread-safe-holder).

Answer (score 0):

No, this code is not correct: `T::~T()` may be called multiple times. Probably, you should use `shared_ptr`.

What do you mean at *active exception*? Does worker thread continue execution after exception is thrown and *how*?

I mean

- if an exception is handled then there is no reason to forward it into another thread, it is already handled.
- else worker thread should be unwinded with exception forwarding and, probably, restarted by the main thread and `std::promise` seems not too bad for this purposes.

So, how is it possible to re-set another exception in worker thread and what for?

Comment: I didn't get you. `T::~T()` is called only in `ThreadSafeStorage::~ThreadSafeHolder()`, which is called once, because only one object of `ThreadSafeStorage` used.

I want to run some function in *many* worker threads. The function might throw, if it throws in one worker I want to stop other worker threads and handle the exception in main thread.

Comment: And `ThreadSafeStorage::~ThreadSafeHolder()` may be called multiple times. Common, it names _copy_. If so, why `std::promise` and `std::fututre` for forwarding result or exception into main thread are bad? Between worker threads you may use `std::shared_ptr< std::exception_ptr >` and check it.

Comment: Sorry, not `std::shared_ptr< std::exception_ptr >` but `std::shared_ptr< std::promise >`. So, since exception is set (means execution is interrupted  and exception is forwarded to main thread) there is no way to set another exception and it's OK, just exit from thread and join it.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr< std::promise >` would not work, because there is no way to test `std::promise` and set an exception atomically, then we fall in dangerous of setting an exception twice (from two thread), but "An exception is thrown if there is no shared state or the shared state already stores a value or exception."

Comment: No, you are not right: you may set exception in a _try-catch block_. But nevertheless there is no reason to test whether exception was set. Just set it! Then catch and exit the thread.

Comment: But how can I signal other threads to stop? In my application I run many worker threads and `!ThreadSafeHolder::IsEmpty()` is an exit condition for them (or they exit if they are out of work).

Comment: @user2932661 it should be shared separately. `boost::iterruption_point()` and `.interrupt()` on a `thread_group`? or other tricks based on a `thread_local` storage-specifier?